# serialize не отправляет данные с формы

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть 2 формы, отличаются только заголовком.
При отправке одной формы скрпит отрабатывал отлично, при добавлении второй формы, я создал дополнительную функцию отправки. Иными словами, каждая функция отвечает за отправку своей формы. Суть проблемы в том, что seriallize не собирает введенную информацию в форму, ни в первую ни во вторую. В итоге на сервер отправляется пустой запрос.

```js
jQuery("#mod-expert").submit(function () {
            var formNm = jQuery('#mod-expert');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/notify',
                data: formNm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    // Вывод текста результата отправки
                    jQuery(".message").removeClass("hidden");
                    jQuery(".message-text").html(data);
                    jQuery(".overlay").removeClass("hidden");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                    // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
                    jQuery(".message").removeClass("hidden");
                    jQuery(".message-text").html(error);
                    jQuery(".overlay").removeClass("hidden");
                }
            });
            return false;
            });
        jQuery("#mod-other-expert").submit(function () {
            var formNm = jQuery('#mod-other-expert');
            console.log(formNm.serialize());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/notify',
                data: formNm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    // Вывод текста результата отправки
                    jQuery(".message").removeClass("hidden");
                    jQuery(".message-text").html(data);
                    jQuery(".overlay").removeClass("hidden");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                    // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
                    jQuery(".message").removeClass("hidden");
                    jQuery(".message-text").html(error);
                    jQuery(".overlay").removeClass("hidden");
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

```html
<div id="mod-expert" class="form-modal">
    <div class="head-modal quest-head">Стать экспертом</div>
    <form id="mod-expert">
      <input type='hidden' name="header" value="Хочу стать экспертом">
      <div class="modal-fields">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required="required"></div>
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="field" class="form-control" id="formData" placeholder="Область знаний"></div>
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="text" id="text" placeholder="В какой области вы эксперт?"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="info" id="info"/>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input class="btn-send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
          <button class="btn-close">Отмена</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="mod-other-expert" class="form-modal">
    <div class="head-modal quest-head">Нужен другой эксперт</div>
    <form id="mod-other-expert">
      <input type='hidden' name="header" value="Нужен другой эксперт">
      <div class="modal-fields">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required="required"></div>
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="formData" class="form-control" id="formData" placeholder="Область знаний"></div>
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="text" id="text" placeholder="С каким вопросом обращаетесь?"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="info" id="info"/>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input class="btn-send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
          <button class="btn-close">Отмена</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Самое трудное в программировании - придумывать названия переменным.*

Выборка `jQuery("#mod-expert")` находит не форму, a `div` с таким же `id`.

Comment: Cпасибо, я предполагал, что просто не находит. но это предположение отбросил т.к. с 1 формой всё отрабатывало. Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, мало опыта имею в работе со скриптами